# Select Statement in PHP Script

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a registration page in PHP and MySQL.

How to prevent user from registering again with the following details: `"fname,lname,user_name,email,bikeno,mobileno"`.

I tried with the following select statement, but its not working.

```
$sql="select * from user_registration where fname='".$fname."' and lname='".$lname."' and user_name='".$user_name."' and  email='".$email."' and bikeno='".$bikeno."' and mobileno='".$mobileno."'";
```

[image: The Values are going to database with same details also]

What I need is if the user gives any duplicate details in these columns the user is not registered.

Comment: If you want to avoid duplicates on individual columns use OR instead of AND

Comment: you should not allow user with same bike number or same mobile number or user name,, Users may have same first name or last name

Comment: Before inserting use select statement if result is 1 then prompt user already created else use insert statement.

Comment: @NishantSolanki yes bro ur right can u tell me the code for that

Comment: @phobia82  $sql="select * from user_registration where  user_name='".$user_name."' OR  email='".$email."' OR bikeno='".$bikeno."' OR mobileno='".$mobileno."'";

Comment: That should work for you, is it?

Comment: On an additional note, you should not store passwords as plain text

Comment: yes bro iam using md5 but when retreving the password from android its not be able to login that's why i i didn't use that. Thank you bro :)

Comment: md5 is a *terrible* idea for passwords and easily cracked.  You should use a salt encrypted hash...  See https://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql="select * from user_registration where fname='".$fname."' or lname='".$lname."' or user_name='".$user_name."' or  email='".$email."' or bikeno='".$bikeno."' or mobileno='".$mobileno."'";

//After select query check if users exist or not as

$result = $con->query($sql);

if($result->num_rows > 0)
{
    //Here Prevent the user registration with the same details
}
else
{
    //Here Insert record into the table
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
$res = mysqli_query($con,"$sql="select * from user_registration where fname='".$fname."' and lname='".$lname."' and user_name='".$user_name."' and  email='".$email."' and bikeno='".$bikeno."' and mobileno='".$mobileno."'";
");

if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 1)
echo "User Already Exist";
else
// run insert query
```